# Validate JSON Schema based on "type" property

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have the following JSON which validates against my current schema:

```
    {
      "information": [
        {
          "value": "closed",
          "type": "power"
        },
        {
          "value": "on",
          "type": "door"
        }
      ]
    }
```

However, I want this validation to fail (since `open`/`closed` should relate to `door`, and `on`/`off` should only relate to `power`.

How can I tie the two together?

My current working schema:

```
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "Type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["power", "door"]
    },
    "Power": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["on", "off"]
    },
    "Door": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["open", "closed"]
    },
    "InformationField": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "type", "value" ],
      "properties": {
        "label": { "type": "string" },
        "value": {
          "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/Power"},
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/Door"}
          ]
        },
        "type": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Type" }
      }
    },
    "Information": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/InformationField" }
    },
  },
  "properties": {
    "information": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Information" }
  },
}
```

I have a lot of types, so I want to do this in the cleanest way possible.

Here is one of my attempts, which fails to validate correctly:

```
{ 
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "Type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["power", "door"]
    },
    "Power": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["on", "off"]
    },
    "Door": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["open", "closed"]
    },
    "InformationField": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "label", "value" ],
      "properties": {
        "label": { "type": "string" },
        "type": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Type" }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "if": {
           "properties": { "type": { "const": "power" } }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": { "value": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Power" } }
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": { "type": { "const": "door" } }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": { "value": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Door" } }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "Information": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/InformationField" }
    },
  },
  "properties": {
    "information": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Information" }
  },
}
```

(Validates, even though it shouldn't ...)

Answer (score 2):

Changed `anyOf` to `allOf` in my attempt, which fixes validation.

**My reasoning as to why this works:**

From the `anyOf` JSON schema spec:

> 5.5.4.2. Conditions for successful validation
>
> An instance validates successfully against this keyword if it validates successfully against at least one schema defined by this keyword's value.

If my first `if` condition is false, then it doesn't evaluate the `then`, *and is therefore valid*.

Using `allOf` evaluates **every** condition's validation (not the condition itself).

Comment: Alternativly, you could add `else: false` to your if/then schemas.